# Can we have a badge at each level when all the bronze/silver/gold have been achieved?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

It would be great if we had a badge that was awarded when all the bronze badges were achieved, etc.

This might spur people on to get badges.

Comment: Welcome to MSO, Rob! I know a -6 might not seem very welcoming, but here on Meta a downvote just means "I disagree with this suggestion," not "you have asked a bad question."

Comment: What about the tag badges? Would we have to earn all of those, too, in order to qualify?

Comment: If the badges themselves aren't enough of an incentive, would a badge for getting badges really help?

Answer (score 11):

Consider Precognitive and Beta on Stack Overflow. Nobody would be eligible for the "all bronzes" badge, and very few would be eligible for the "all silvers" badge. Also, no new users will ever be eligible for "all silvers." Presumably the "all X" badges would be gold, so nobody would be eligible for "all golds" either.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that this is useful. More badges can be added in the future. Should we revoke the existing "I earned all badges!" badge on users who don't meet the requirements for the new badges?

Answer (score 2):

Great idea! A bronze badge for "All Bronze Badges". But then, until you've earned this badge, you haven't actually earned all bronze badges... hmmm... maybe this badge **already exists** but, paradoxically, **no one has ever earned it**! Something to think about...

Comment: Thinking about this caused a Stack Overflow error.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create a meta-badge, it would be better to propose a new badge that rewards a behavior we desire to promote, but that is not currently rewarded by either reputation or the existing badges.

For example, we have a growing problem with unanswered questions because only fresh questions with high views have much reputation potential.  Orthogonal to Nice Answer, a bronze badge could be awarded for each ten accepted answers provided 24 hours after the questions are asked.

The point is use your imagination to come up with an idea to try to promote a behavior and then suggest it.